# Trigger For this Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created this procedure for inserting data into the database, this is working fine. Now I want to create a trigger which prevents insertion of duplicate rows. I'm using SQL Server 2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEmployee]
  @Stu_id nvarchar(50),
  @Status int,
  @Time nvarchar(50),
  @Date nvarchar(50),
  @Sub_id nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO  Attendanc (Stu_id, Status, Timing, Dates, Sub_id )
  VALUES (@Stu_id, @Status, @Time, @Date, @Sub_id)
END
```

Comment: You should provide what you tried in order to get what you need. As you haven't, this seems out-of-topic for this site.

Comment: I am trying this for first time so, i have no clue how to create triggers.

Comment: I've added the appropriate tags to this question, but I agree with @ZygD that there's not enough information in your question to show *what you've tried for this actual problem*.

Comment: @user2747666 Why you need trigger for avoiding duplicates? You can do by `IF Exists` before insert query.

Comment: If you concider triggers, why not to use unique constraint?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, a trigger is not the appropriate tool for the job you want to do. To prevent duplicate data in your table you should add a [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) on the columns that shouldn't be duplicated.

another option is adding a [unique index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of a unique constraint. This is useful for optimizing select statements, but may have a bad effect on updating or inserting data.

After you add a unique constraint or index, 
any attempt to insert duplicated data to these columns will cause sql server to raise an error.
Note: you will also not be able to update rows if the result of the update will cause these columns to have duplicate data.

So how do you avoid these errors?
You add a check to your procedure before inserting the data - something like this:

```
-- Assuming the unique constraint is on columns Status and Sub_id
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Attendanc WHERE Status = @Status AND Sub_id = @Sub_id) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  Attendanc (Stu_id, Status, Timing, Dates, Sub_id )
END
```

Update statements can be a little trickier to check, but still possible (here's a quick example):

```
-- Still assuming the unique constraint is on columns Status and Sub_id
UPDATE A 
SET A.Status = @Status
FROM Attendanc A INNER JOIN Attendanc B ON(A.Sub_id = B.Sub_id)
WHERE A.Stu_id = @Stu_id
AND B.Status <> @Status
```

This will update Status column only if the value will not violate the multi-column unique constraint (on Status and Sub_Id)